# Can't get cron to work

Tags: cron, sitemaps

I try to set up cron to generate my site map.

I defined the google sitemap in catalog > google sitemap.
I also defined the system > configuration > catalog > google sitemap generation  to every day

I then configured cron in system > configuration > system > cron as follow :

[image]

As no update are made on my sitemap files, I implemented the following php
[php cron job monitor](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/51142/P120/#t351010)

But no tasks are displayed….

Furthermore, when I do a crontab -l I have i got an error saying "No crontab for *user*"

Could you help me on that please?

Comment: Did you run the cron.sh file?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to setup the crontab for the user on your server.

Magento provides some [generic instructions](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job) on how to do this.

Basically you should add the following lines to your crontab file.

```
MAILTO=your.user@your.server.com

*/5 * * * *  /bin/sh /path/to/your/magento/cron.sh
```

Comment: thanks for your help. If I do /bin/sh I receive the mail but saying : /bin/sh: bin/sh: No such file or directory. If I put just sh, cron is not working any more…
In both case, my magento sitemap is not updated

Comment: @Alexglvr interesting, you could always use the cron.php file and update your cron to something along the lines of `*/5 * * * *  php /path/to/your/magento/cron.php`

Comment: I managed to run cron properly using the php :
*/5 * * * *  php /path/to/your/magento/cron.php

Comment: but it does not update my sitemaps (declared in admin panel Catalog > google sitemaps). Their path is magento install dir/sitemap and /sitemapeu: do I have to add something in the cron.php to make them updated?

Answer (score 2):

Find out what folder your Magento installation is in via ssh.

'cd' into the magento root folder and type 'pwd' to get the path to the current folder (copy the result).

type 'crontab -e' to create a new crontab file.

paste this into the file:

```
*/5 * * * *  sh [magento path]/cron.sh
```

*/5 means the crontab will be executed every 5 minutes.

exit and save the cronjob by typing ':wq'

to email results of cronjob executions write this on the first line of the crontab

```
MAILTO=[email address]
```

note however that this will send an email every 5 minutes, so I'd advise to remove this after testing.